# highcharts & rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts

Hi I'm trying to use highcharts on my app...for that I'm following the [highcharts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/223-charts?view=asciicast) the script works but when I want to put the real data I got this :
[image]

I've followed all the steps however here is my model:

```
class TankingLog < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :gas_station 
belongs_to :car
attr_accessible :car_id, :cost, :date, :gallon, :gas_station_id, :km
validates_presence_of :cost, :date,:gallon,:km
validates_numericality_of :cost, :gallon
validates_numericality_of :km #:only_integer
def self.total_on(date)
    where("date(date) = ?",date).sum(:cost)
end
end
```

and here is my html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Listing Tankings</h1>
  <% if @tankinglog.count<1 %>
    <p>
    There are no tankings for this car. Do you want to <%= link_to 'create a new tanking', new_user_car_tanking_log_path(@user, @car)%>
    </p>
  <% else %>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
      new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: { renderTo: 'foo_chart' },
      title: { text: 'Tankings by Day' },
      xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
      yAxis: {
      title: { text: 'Cost' }
    },
      series: [{
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: <%= 0.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
        data: [data: <%= (1.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| TankingLog.total_on(date).to_f}.inspect %>]
      }]
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="foo_chart" style="width: 560px; height: 300px;"></div>

    <table class="table table-condensed">
      <tr>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Gallon</th>
        <th>Km</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Gas Station's id</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <% for tankinglog in @tankinglog  %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= number_to_currency (tankinglog.cost) %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.gallon %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.km %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.date %></td>
          <td><%= tankinglog.gas_station_id %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
    <br />
    <%= link_to 'New tanking', new_user_car_tanking_log_path(@user, @car), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <br />
  <%= link_to 'back', user_cars_path(current_user), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
```

thanks for your help

also here is that my script shows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the foo_chart div that it is trying to render to? Have you included jQuery's js before including highcharts' js? What are the contents of the "Console" of the browser? Does the console have any js errors? Can you share the generated html, as text not image?

How to get errors from console (Chrome)
[image]

Clicking on the line number will take you to the exact place where js broke

Comment: Ya, saw your scripts, was looking at the images primarily, so missed it first time. Console data would be best help

Comment: Check the image in edited answer, clicking on the line number will take you to the exact place where js broke

Answer (score 0):

was my fault, I had a syntax error, it was:

```
series: [{
        pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
        pointStart: <%= 0.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
        data: <%= (0.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| TankingLog.total_on(date).to_f}.inspect %>
      }]
```

isntead

```
series: [{
    pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
    pointStart: <%= 0.weeks.ago.at_midnight.to_i * 1000 %>,
    data: [data: <%= (1.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| TankingLog.total_on(date).to_f}.inspect %>]
  }]
```

thanks for help